# Como faço para chamar um método dentro de um loop?

Tags: javascript, ionic, firebase

Estou tentando executar uma função ,cuja qual tenho uma chamada de outra função dentro de um *loop*, porém o `return` da função só carrega a primeira entrada de método. Então, como faço para chamar um método dentro de um *loop*? Segue o código:

função 1:

```
componentesGrafico() {
    var i, j;
    var valores; 
    console.log(this.arraySlide[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < this.arraySlide.length;i++) {
        valores = this.db.queryDatabase(this.arraySlide[i]);
        console.log(valores); 
    }
```

função 2:

```
queryDatabase(id) {
    var grupo = '/EMPRESA/COMPBI/';
    var db = this.afd.database.ref(grupo).orderByKey();
    var valores = new Array(); 
    db.startAt(id).endAt(id+"\uf8ff").on("child_added",function (snapshot) {
        valores.push(snapshot.key);
        console.log(snapshot.key);
    });
    return valores;
}
```

Comment: Eu apenas indentei seu código, sem tirar nem adicionar nada. Me parece faltar um fecha-chave em algum lugar.

Comment: o codigo compila se colocar uma chave '}' no final da função 1, porém meu problema é o retorno da função dois. Ele executa o 'loop' de forma correta, porém o meu resultado e o primeiro da query no firebase.

Comment: Só para eu poder entender um pouco melhor. O segundo método em algum momento não executa uma função assíncrona? Se sim, não irá funcionar desta forma pois ele provavelmente, irá retornar um Promise. Terá de ajustar a sua lógica, caso seja isso mesmo. Mas não tenho certeza se ele faz realmente essa chamada assíncrona. Talvez seja um "norte"!

Answer (score 0):

Tal como o Diego disse: a 2ª função funciona de forma assíncrona. Quando você retorna o array de valores, ele ainda não foi inicializado. Você terá de colocar o corpo da função 2 na função 1:

```
componentesGrafico() {
    var i, j;
    var valores; 
    console.log(this.arraySlide[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < this.arraySlide.length;i++) {
        valores = new Array();
        var grupo = '/EMPRESA/COMPBI/';
        var db = this.afd.database.ref(grupo).orderByKey();
        db.startAt(id).endAt(id+"\uf8ff").on("child_added",function (snapshot) {
            valores.push(snapshot.key);
            console.log(snapshot.key);
        });
        console.log(valores); 
    }
}
```